# Deploying jars for production in Maven

Tags: java, maven, deployment, dependencies, copy

I have multiple Java projects (packaged to jars) in my product which have a single `pom` combining them as modules. Each of the projects has different dependencies and their combined dependencies are defined in the parent `pom`. I want to prepare the output for production and do the following:

1. deploy (copy) all my jars to a single location
2. copy the 3rd party jars from all projects to a different single folder
3. copy the configuration files (found under the src/main/resources) from all the projects to a third folder.

Anyone knows of a way to do it without having to manually copy each of the above for all the projects? I also want my future projects to support this deployment procedure without having to work too hard and specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will summarize What I did in the assembly XML (to answer all of my issues) in addition to Andrey Borisov answer.

1. deploy (copy) all my jars to a single location **[Used the "moduleset" element]**
2. copy the 3rd party jars from all projects to a different **[Used the "dependencySets" element]**
3. copy the configuration files (found under the src/main/resources) from all the projects to a third folder. **[Used the "fileset" element]**

   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
       bin
       
           dir
       
       false

   ```
   <moduleSets>
       <moduleSet>
           <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
           <binaries>
               <outputDirectory>modules</outputDirectory>
               <unpack>false</unpack>
           </binaries>
       </moduleSet>
   </moduleSets>


   <dependencySets>
       <dependencySet>
           <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
           <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
       </dependencySet>
   </dependencySets>

   <fileSets>
       <fileSet>
           <directory>my DIR 1</directory>
           <excludes>
               <exclude>*log4j*</exclude>
           </excludes>
           <outputDirectory>resources</outputDirectory>
       </fileSet>
       <fileSet>
           <directory>my DIR 2</directory>
           <outputDirectory>resources</outputDirectory>
       </fileSet>
   </fileSets>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Maven assembly plugin for this - here is example of zipping distributive (on production you need then just to unzip):

```xml
  <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>${project.basedir}/src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

and assembly XML

```xml
 <assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
<id>${env}</id>
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        <includes>
            <include>com.mycompany:ear-project</include>
            <include>com.mycompany:jnlp-project</include>
        </includes>
        <outputDirectory>libs</outputDirectory>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>

<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>target/docbook/pdf</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>index.pdf</include>
        </includes>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

Please NOTE that for your 2 projects (EAR, JNLP) you can place dependencies via **outputDirectory** configuration.

Comment: I tried your code template and got some dependencies to work. The main problem remains the resources folders. When using the "filesets" element, I need to specify the exact resource folders to copy. I want to automatically copy all the content of ALL the child modules of the project without specifying directories and/or file names manually.

Comment: Yes. CC. What does it have to do with my question?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same requirements in my project.

There is a difference between using the Jenkins with ClearCase and SVN.
If you were using SVN you should have checked out your projects into your main project, and worked on them like there were on the same dir.

After checking out my child projects I can work on them, in the example you can see a portion from the assembly.xml, in which core and scheduler are the child projects.

```
</fileSet>
 <fileSet>
  <directory>./core/src/main/resources/</directory>
  <outputDirectory>./examples</outputDirectory>
  <includes>
    <include>*</include>
  </includes>
</fileSet>
<fileSet>
  <directory>./scheduler/src/main/resources/</directory>
  <outputDirectory>./examples</outputDirectory>
  <includes>
    <include>*</include>
  </includes>
</fileSet>
```

This will basically copy the resources folder content into the main project example project.

You can do the same here, if all you projects are on the same vob, and available, you should specify a relative location to which you are going to copy all your resources.
For example:

```
</fileSet>
 <fileSet>
  <directory>../../../your_sub_project1/src/main/resources/</directory>
  <outputDirectory>./examples</outputDirectory>
  <includes>
    <include>*</include>
  </includes>
</fileSet>
<fileSet>
  <directory>../../../your_sub_project2/src/main/resources/</directory>
  <outputDirectory>./examples</outputDirectory>
  <includes>
    <include>*</include>
  </includes>
</fileSet>
```

This way, when running the primary pom, you will be able to access the content of the sub projects and copy the resources to a certain folder.
Hope it helps..